# convert text/plain to object

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

Need to convert return type of text/pain from web service 
https://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-Modified.meta to below object in C#

```
public class NvdMetaData
{
    public DateTime lastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public int zipSize { get; set; }
    public int gzSize { get; set; }
    public string sha256 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try parsing your web service response to appropriate object type.

Comment: So go write some code. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to `deserialize` your plain text/JSON string.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
NvdMetaData meta_list = 
          (NvdMetaData)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(webServiceResponse);
```

Comment: got error  Invalid JSON primitive: lastModifiedDate.

Comment: Can you post your plain text here?

Comment: this is the string returned on response
lastModifiedDate:2016-06-14T01:02:28-04:00\r\nsize:3294252\r\nzipSize:216866\r\ngzSize:216724\r\nsha256:888baccf0f83e075984f357db21afd6f4cdd4922c93dc700c3623644b07848df

Comment: can you first of all do some manipulation to your plain text and make it clear? remove \r\n.

Comment: added logic to remove \r\n and below is the output

lastModifiedDate:2016-06-14T20:02:41-04:00
size:3579357
zipSize:231377
gzSize:231235
sha256:0080ee8b8bd6a38af93942ade06d892f72bbbad533480f783bca0d7690e844bf

Comment: Can you convert your service to return you JOSn string rather than HTML?